# Broken compiler: fatal error: _mingw.h: No such file or directory

Tags: compiling, windows-subsystem-for-linux, g++

I have broken my compilation and not sure if it is possible to fix it without reinstalling everything from scratch.

I cannot compile the simplest program:

```
#include "math.h"

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

It compiles on my backup version, of course, but I am trying to avoid having to revert to the working version, as I have installed a lot things since then... and apparently broke something in the process.

From the error, it seems that compiler is trying to use `_mingw.h` header. Why? I am not using MinGW. I am using the same compiler that works without issues in my backup version (I have even tried to install another version of `g++` from `apt-get` to confirm that changing compiler does not help.) The error message:

```
 In file included from /usr/local/include/crtdefs.h:10:0,
                  from /usr/local/include/sys/cdefs.h:7,
                  from /usr/include/features.h:424,
                  from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/os_defines.h:39,
                  from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/c++config.h:533,
                  from /usr/include/c++/7/cmath:41,
                  from /usr/include/c++/7/math.h:36,
                  from /mnt/c/test/main.cpp:1: /usr/local/include/corecrt.h:10:10: fatal error: _mingw.h: No such
 file or directory  #include <_mingw.h>
           ^~~~~~~~~~ compilation terminated.
```

I know that `_mingw.h` file does not exist. That is not the issue. The issue that `g++` even requires it: on my backup version this header also does not exist and is not included.

Output from `g++ -M main.cpp` on the backup version (note how it includes `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/cdefs.h` and not `/usr/local/include/sys/cdefs.h` like the broken version).

```
main.o: /mnt/c/test/main.cpp /usr/include/stdc-predef.h \
 /usr/include/c++/7/math.h /usr/include/c++/7/cmath \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/c++config.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/os_defines.h \
 /usr/include/features.h /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/cdefs.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/wordsize.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/long-double.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnu/stubs.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnu/stubs-64.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/cpu_defines.h \
 /usr/include/c++/7/bits/cpp_type_traits.h \
 /usr/include/c++/7/ext/type_traits.h /usr/include/math.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/libc-header-start.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/typesizes.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/math-vector.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/libm-simd-decl-stubs.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/floatn.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/floatn-common.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/flt-eval-method.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/fp-logb.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/fp-fast.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls-helper-functions.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/iscanonical.h \
 /usr/include/c++/7/bits/std_abs.h /usr/include/stdlib.h \
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include/stddef.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/waitflags.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/waitstatus.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types/locale_t.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types/__locale_t.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types/clock_t.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types/clockid_t.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types/time_t.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types/timer_t.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdint-intn.h /usr/include/endian.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/endian.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/byteswap.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/byteswap-16.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/uintn-identity.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/select.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/select.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types/sigset_t.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types/__sigset_t.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types/struct_timeval.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types/struct_timespec.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/sysmacros.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/sysmacros.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/pthreadtypes.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/thread-shared-types.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/pthreadtypes-arch.h \
 /usr/include/alloca.h /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdlib-float.h
```

I am on WSL2 if that matters to the issue. I do not have any `*mingw*` packages listed in `dpkg --list`.

Comment: So the issue seems to be that you have incompatible header files in /usr/local/include - why? where do these come from? no Ubuntu package would place files there

Comment: @steeldriver That is exactly what I wanted to know :D I had to install many things manually, and it seems at some point I installed wrong headers. I was trying to find a way to track how they got there, what package includes those... But never found a way to do that and just had to clean folder manually.

Comment: ... so did that resolve the issue?

Comment: @steeldriver Yes, but I had to remove all headers from the directory and reinstall some other headers that were correct, as I did not find a way how to automatically detect which headers/package were installed wrongly. If someone knows the way to do that automatically without affecting other packages, that would be great to have as an answer to this quesiton.